# How to assign response from Api to an array using fetch function

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, api, react-hooks

I want to assign response in Fruits array ones I fetched the data from Api using fetch...But I am  getting empty array when console.log.. I am getting the response from Api but not able to assign it to fruits
I am doing this way:  `.then(data => Fruits);`

```
let Fruits = []



     useEffect(() => {
      
      const requestOptions = {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIwicm9sZSI6ImV4cGVydCJ9.6pYrAr_En0nl4N52oP1O7WRJA6PPFGCzUebauBIOEnc", },
          body: JSON.stringify({"dfdfdffd"})
      };
     
          fetch('https://d.com/audis/el/lt', requestOptions)
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(data => Fruits);    

 
     }, []);
```

Comment: You most likely want to make `Fruits` state: `const [fruits, setFruits] = useState([]);`, and then set your state: `.then(data => setFruits(data));`. When you use state, your component will rerender (so then you can make your component use fruits to display content)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a state

```js
const [fruits, setFruits] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
      
      const requestOptions = {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIwicm9sZSI6ImV4cGVydCJ9.6pYrAr_En0nl4N52oP1O7WRJA6PPFGCzUebauBIOEnc", },
          body: JSON.stringify({"firebase_id":"foCzPM8MgOtg1"})
      };
     
          fetch('https://d.com/audis/el/lt', requestOptions)
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(data => setFruits(data);    
     }, []);
```

Answer (score 4):

You're not assigning `data` to anything. Try:

```js
fetch('https://d.com/audis/el/lt', requestOptions)
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(data => Fruits = data);
```

Also, you should use a state do store the information.

```js
const [fruits, setFruits] = useState();

fetch('https://d.com/audis/el/lt', requestOptions)
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(data => setFruits(data));
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe use a state?

```js
    const [fruits, setFruits] = useState([])
    useEffect(() => {
      
      const requestOptions = {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIwicm9sZSI6ImV4cGVydCJ9.6pYrAr_En0nl4N52oP1O7WRJA6PPFGCzUebauBIOEnc", },
          body: JSON.stringify({"firebase_id":"foCzPM8MgOtg1"})
      };
     
          fetch('https://d.com/audis/el/lt', requestOptions)
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(data => setFruits(data));    

       
  
 
     }, []);
     console.log(fruits);
```

Comment: Great minds think alike :)